# How to fix this Oauth 2.0 error redirecting

Tags: java, oauth-2.0, spring-security-oauth2

[image]400. That’s an error.  Error: redirect_uri_mismatch  The redirect URI in the request, http://testing.com:8008/login, does not match the ones authorized for the OAuth client. To update the authorized redirect URIs, visit:

Authorized redirect URIs in the credential page is http://testing.com:8008/success but it always redirects to http://testing.com:8008/login don't know what is going wrong here could someone help.

My application.yml file for config is below.

```
security:
  oauth2:
    client:
      clientId: 701691307057-184m2p0ce76k.apps.googleusercontent.com
      clientSecret: 7186351
      pre-established-redirect-uri: http://testing.com:8008/success
      accessTokenUri: https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v3/token
      userAuthorizationUri: https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth
      tokenName: oauth_token
      authenticationScheme: query
      clientAuthenticationScheme: form
      scope: profile email
    resource:
      userInfoUri: https://www.googleapis.com/userinfo/v2/me
      preferTokenInfo: false
```

Web security configuration class below.

```
@EnableOAuth2Sso
@Configuration
public class WebSecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .csrf()
                .disable()
                .antMatcher("/**")
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/", "/home", "/success")
                .permitAll()
                .anyRequest()
                .authenticated();
    }
}
```

Controllers below

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/")
public class WelcomeController {

    @RequestMapping(value = {"home"}, method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String welcomePage(){
        return "welcomePageAfterSignin";
    }

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String welcomePage2(){
        return "welcomePage";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = {"success"}, method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String AfterSignIn(){
        return "success";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "user")
    public Principal user(Principal principal) {
        return principal;
    }
}
```

Comment: If you are being redirected to /login on by Spring Security that means the URL /success is protected and not accessible without authentication. You need to allow it to be accessed without authentication.

Comment: Yes, makes sense but whole purpose of using google sign in redirect will be lost. As I want to redirect to /success after sign in using Oauth. If I allow /success than it will not authenticate using Oauth.

Answer (score 0):

[image]    Actually nothing is wrong,  you are being redirected to spring security login page.

what you missing is **credentials of spring-security**.

Look closely into the logs and you will see password something like `Using generated security password: 5608543f-48fd-46ae-94a4-3f7094aa0d53`

so u need to enter these credentials in your login page. 
Username is by default : `user`
password is generated each time in logs (like) : `5608543f-48fd-46ae-94a4-3f7094aa0d53`

only then you will be redirected to your google page or the api's which you have exposed.

adding a picture for your reference[image]

Comment: I don't want to use in build spring login feature so that I can use google sign in for my web app I configured it to do that. But I am getting redirect error.

Comment: then kindly show your code, other than this config file, show that we can understand, better.

Comment: sorry, i forgot to mention, kindly share your jsp's folder structure too, because it is important.

Answer (score 0):

- Make sure to check the protocol "http://" or "https://" as google checks protocol as well. Better to add both URL in the list.
- This seems quite strange and annoying that no "one" solution is there. for me http://localhost:8000 did not worked out but http://localhost:8000/ worked out.

Comment: copied from another StackOverflow answers